# How much current is available with a buck converter? (re: 20V/5A to 5V/20A?)

Tags: current, buck

I've been trying to research this as much as possible but I'm still a little confused.

If I'm using a PSU rated for 20V / 5A, can a typical buck converter output 5V / 20A?  (assuming 100% efficiency which I know is impossible)

Everything I've read states that a buck converter will output the same power (minus efficiency loss) stated as:  Input (20V x 5A = 100W) allows 100W - (efficiency loss) but that doesn't really address the current limit on the power source?

Comment: what are you asking about the current limit of the source?

Comment: I'm confused by your assertion that the power source current limit is an issue. The buck converter will draw approx. 5 A @ 20 V when supplying 100 watts in the form of 20 A @ 5 V

Comment: Buck converters also have their own output current ratings. So if you choose one rated at 3A, you'll get up to 3A out of it (drawing nearly 1A from 20V)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "typical buck converter", you get (or build) one suitable to do what you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect an ideal 5V @ 20A buck converter on the output of 20V @ 5A power source, the current drawn from 20V won't be 20A, rather 5A. So, it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

> If I'm using a PSU rated for 20V / 5A, can a typical buck converter output 5V / 20A? (assuming 100% efficiency which I know is impossible)

In theory, with 100% efficiency, yes.

> Everything I've read states that a buck converter will output the same power (minus efficiency loss) stated as: Input (20V x 5A = 100W) allows 100W - (efficiency loss) but that doesn't really address the current limit on the power source?

Not sure what you're asking but...

In your ideal scenario, the power source has a perfectly accurate current limit (or overcurrent protection) that corresponds exactly to the buck's maximum input current.

A real converter, with say 90% efficiency, that outputs 5V 20A would need to pull 5.6A from the 20V supply (100Wout / 90% / 20Vin == 5.6A).

However, if the power supply is not exactly 20V, then input current will vary in inverse proportion: when input voltage goes down, current goes up to maintain output power.

On startup, it could draw more than the maximum specified long-term current if the load has large capacitors. How much depends on how the DC-DC implements soft-start.

The maximum input current of the converter, or its current limit if it has one, may not be very accurate. It is often cheaper to have an inaccurate current limit, as long as that works as protection.

Likewise the power supply's output current limit also has a tolerance.

So you should allow some margin between the maximum input current and the power supply's capabilities. If the buck has a maximum input current of 5A and the power supply has a maximum output current of 5A, then depending on tolerances and luck, it may work up to the maximum current you want, or trip the current limit before that.

If you care about efficiency and often use it at high load, it may also be worth it to overspec both the DC-DC and the power supply so they both work at their peak efficiency point.

Answer (score 0):

Converters don't really care about the input power source as long as it can provide the converter's output power divided by the efficiency within the permissible input voltage specifications (note that most converters will have varying efficiency with changing input voltage).  It's up to the designer to make sure that the input power source is sized correctly.  That said, I do not recommend planning to run either the converter or its power source at 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A switching power supply, like a buck or boost converter, is very much the modern DC version of the good old AC transformer. The product of voltage times current is in principle the same on both sides, ignoring small losses.

The reason is that the transformer temporarily stores the electrical energy of the primary side in the magnetic field, which is then converted to the electrical energy on the secondary side. Primary and secondary voltages may differ, but power on each side is the same.

Something similar happens in the switching power supply with intermediate storage of pulses in the fields of the inductor and capacitor.